# Import data from list box in a form to another

Tags: c#

I have an application with two forms. In the first form I have a list box. Now I want to import the data from the list box of the first form to the second form in C# can this be done and if I can do this. How can I make it?

Comment: There is MANY options here. You can expose the listbox as a public property, encapsulate it behind a method, have a third class acting as a view model, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form is not open yet, then you could make the constructor for the second form allow a [ListView.ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and add the items to the ListBox that way.

For example:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Form2(listBox1.Items).Show();
}
```

Then in the other form's constructor:

```
public Form2(ListBox.ObjectCollection items)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
}
```